# Get SMS Details From its ID Android

Tags: android, sms, android-cursor

I want to get Details of SMS(Number, Text Body, Time of coming); And i only know the id of sms.
Can i query to "content://sms" with this id and get details?

At the moment i can make a loop and query for every message and get details. But that is not efficient when you have to get single sms details 10 times from 1000 sms.....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured it out myself:

```
Uri myMessage = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor c = cr.query(myMessage, new String[] { "_id", "address", "date", "body","read" },"_id = "+smsID, null, null);

c.moveToFirst();

String Number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();

String ReadStatus = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("read"));
String Body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
            
c.close();
```

I was missing the condition and moving the cursor to first.

Comment: Frarhan, is that retrieval smswhich have same id in database ?