# Get message _id from onReceive android

Tags: android, sms

I have tried to get a message id which is saved in phone associated with each message.But I failed to get it. My existing code is here

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
        if (intentExtras != null) {
            Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
            String smsMessageStr = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
                SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage
                        .createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);

                smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
            //  smsMessageId = how to get message id ?
                long millis= smsMessage.getTimestampMillis();

                Date date = new Date(millis);
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                // set the calendar to start of today
                c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
                c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
                c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                // and get that as a Date
                Date today = c.getTime();

                if (date.before(today)) {
                    smsDate = (String) DateFormat.format(" MMMM dd ", new Date(
                            millis));
                } else {
                    smsDate = (String) DateFormat.format("  h:mm ",
                            new Date(millis));
                }

                if (pre_address.equals(address)) {

                    smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
                    smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";
                }
            }

            SMSItem smsItem = new SMSItem();
            smsItem.sms = smsBody ; 
            smsItem.status = false;
            smsItem.time = smsDate;

            Toast.makeText(context, smsMessageStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // this will update the UI with message
            SmsActivity inst = SmsActivity.instance();
            if (inst != null) {
                inst.updateList(smsBody);
                if (pre_address.equals(address))
                    inst.Notify(inst.getMessageCountUnread()
                            + " unread message", address);
            }
        }
```

By this I get sms body and sender number. But I know there exist a unique number for every message in android phone, I retrieved it. But unable to retrieved in onReceive methods.How can I retrieve message id in onReceive methods ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042702/get-sms-details-from-its-id-android

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri myMessage = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor c = cr.query(myMessage, new String[] { "_id", "address", "date", "body","read" },"_id = "+smsID, null, null);

c.moveToFirst();

String Number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();

String ReadStatus = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("read"));
String Body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();

c.close();
```